# How to convert text file to avro in apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

we're trying to convert text file(comma delimited) to avro using ConvertCSVToAvro in Nifi but output is a text file from ConvertCSVToAvro processor.

Comment: provide the input and output examples, processor parameters, and describe what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Teekoji Rao BeLkAr,

to convert csv to avro,

1. You need to split the text first as line by line using SplitText Processor.
2. use regex to extract values by using ExtractText processor, it will results values as attributes for the each flow file.
3. ReplaceText processor to replace the attributes as contents of the flowfile.
4. InferAvroSchema processor to get schema of the flowfile content.
5. ConvertCSVToAvro processor to convert the flowfile contents into Avro format
   **Note:-** i have used pipe(|) as delimiter in ReplaceText processor for replacement value, you can use any delimiter as you like. But the delimiter needs to match with InferAvroSchema csv header definition

   **All the configurations for the processors are mentioned in the link,**

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/131332/nifi-convert-text-file-consisting-of-key-value-pai.html?childToView=131440#answer-131440][1]